# insert date value into oracle using java not working

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, oracle11g

I'm trying to insert date format into Oracle from Java EE Eclipes.  I'm able to insert a null value but not date value.  The date prints out in the console okay but does not update the database.
Here are my queries:

**Inserting Date value: (NOT WORKING)** Console output for uDate = 20/Sep/16

```
public void updateUnsubscribe(String empid) { 
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yy");
  String uDate = df.format(new Date());
  String unSub = "udate MYDB set edate ='" + uDate + '" where emp = "empid"';
}
```

**Inserting NULL value: (WORKING)** Console output for uDate = null

```
public void updateSubscribe(String empid) { 
  Date toNull = null;
  String sub = "udate MYDB set edate ='" + toNull + '" where emp = "empid"';
}
```

I don't get any errors, at all, the only issue is the date field not inserting the date.  What am I missing? Am I not formatting my date field correctly.

Comment: Your DateFormat is probably wrong (try d.d./MM/yy)

Comment: what's your date format in oracle? is it same as dd/MMM/yy?

Comment: output is like this 'Tue SEp 20 11:45:02 UTC 2016'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use oracle to_date function to convert varchar to date value, for your example:

```
public void updateUnsubscribe(String empid) { 
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
  String uDate = df.format(new Date());
  String unSub = "udate MYDB set edate =to_date('" + uDate + ', 'dd/MM/yyyy')" where emp = "empid"';
}
```

But rather that, it is better to use JDBC PreparedStatement for this task:

```
public void updateUnsubscribe(String empid) { 
  PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("update MYDB set edate=? where emp=?");
  ps.setTimestamp(1, new java.sql.Timestamp(new Date()));
  ps.setString(2, empid);
  ps.executeUpdate();
}
```